# Either wait X seconds or for a user input

Tags: ios, swift

I'm very new to swift so even this is a bit complicated to me at this point; sorry for sounding dumb if I do

Preface:
I have a main view controller(lets call it viewA) and a UIView which gets its functionality from a .xib file, let's call this viewB

This is all in the single main view controller page

The problem:
So i want my ViewController to execute a bunch of methods in sequence one of which is to call the result from a function in this viewB(its a subview so i cant use segues)

So in the function i want to return the result only when either--

1. A button to be pressed
2. 30 seconds have passed

Whats the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

EDIT: 
In a nutshell i want to make my main queue execution wait till there is an input from the player or 30 seconds have passed

Code structure:

```
ViewController:
class ViewController{

var viewB:CustomView
//methods
function to execute{
viewB.executeFunction()
}
}
```

CustomView:

```
class CustomView:UIView{

//functions of initializing buttons and text boxes
func executeFunction(){
//wait for a user input to complete then return from this function. i cant figure out how this works
}

}
```

[Image of the UI idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydhsu.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your questions. And provide some code if you have write there.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! Updated my description; my code is quite huge so i cant paste it here but it'll give you the snippet

Comment: 30 seconds  ?? Purpose ?

Comment: its the timeout for the user. its like a game i told myself to make as a lesson i have like 4 players and i wait for an action from each of those; players can make a play before others do but if thy haven't played yet and its their turn then they have 30s to select one of the buttons

Comment: Ok. Understood. Each of them what action ? After 30 secs, Button has to Visible ?

Comment: all players have their buttons visible all the time. lets say the players have a text box each and a text area in the middle. each player(each view is a player) has to type a word and press the button and it gets appended to the text area at the end of their turn.
Now if a player doesn't play their turn for 30s then their turn ends by timeout and they are removed from the game

Comment: @AshutoshSultania  If you have image for your ui then please provide. like as, mock image.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Option 1** is more suitable for your scenario. You can call the block when the button in your nib is pressed. Following is the code how you can use block in swift:

```
// Code for your UIViewController
func presentPopup() {
    let popup = NibClassName.instantiateViewFromNib()
    popup.btnPressBlock = { [unowned self] (success) -> () in
        // Code after button of UIView pressed
    }
    popup.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(popup)
}

// Code of your UIView class file
var btnPressBlock: ((Bool) -> ())?

class func instantiateViewFromNib() -> NibClassName {
    let obj = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NibName", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! NibClassName
    return obj
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    btnPressBlock!(true)
    removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: How your nib file init in your view controller? Please update the code for it in your question.

Comment: i just used the nib file as the class for my UIViews